# SQL Server: Is deny permission required for custom DB role?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to set up a custom read-only database role, which only grants select permission on tables.

My question is: do I still need to explicitly DENY update/insert/delete/execute on this database role?

I want to understand the difference between having explicit deny permissions in this case, vs not having them.

Comment: Permissions you don't grant are simply not present. You don't need to `DENY` permissions a role won't have in the first place (`DENY` should be used very sparingly; it typically indicates a problem with the permission structure). Note that the role you propose already exists in the form of the standard `db_datareader` role, unless your intent is to create one that only has `SELECT` permission on *some* tables.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you. Our company doesn't want us to use any of the built-in roles.

Comment: Although not using any of the built-in roles is good in principle (as it prevents you from getting complacent with assigning too many permissions) keep in mind that you will have gained (almost) nothing if you create a custom role that is defined in terms of being a read-only role, as that just means you've created an alias for `db_datareader`. The best approach is to create a custom role per application (group), and assign these only the absolute minimum permissions they need -- i.e. per table/stored procedure/whatever.

Comment: `DENY` is normally only used if the user/login has been also given the `GRANT` permission by something else; such as another role or implicitly by permission chaining (for example you can `GRANT` a use to `SELECT` from a `VIEW` but not the underlying tables, and they will be able to use the `VIEW`, but still not `SELECT directly from the tables). If it's just to read tables, then there's unlikely to be any implied permissions.